# How to drop sqlite table after it already exists in c#

Tags: c#, sqlite

**So my error is: table chang9 already exists.**

I googled around, and people said to drop the table after you run it, hence i used  (with no luck):

```
 sqlite_cmd.CommandText = " DROP Table 'chang9'";
```

**Maybe there's a syntax issue with it? But Here is my full code:**(note: drop table section is at end of code)

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // We use these three SQLite objects:
        SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn;
        SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;

        // create a new database connection: // Maybe error here - video was different
        sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=database.db;Version=3;");

        // open the connection:
        sqlite_conn.Open();

        // create a new SQL command:
        sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();

        // Let the SQLiteCommand object know our SQL-Query:
        sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE chang9 (Seq text, Field text, Desc text, Len text, Dec text, Typ text, Percnt text, Pop text, Alzero text, MaxLen text );";

        // Now lets execute the SQL                                                                                  
        sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO chang9 (Seq, Field, Desc, Len, Dec, Typ, Percnt, Pop, Alzero, MaxLen) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10)";
        sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", 6);  // dummy initial values 
        sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", 878); 
        sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", 56);
        sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", 6);
        sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", 546);
        sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", 565);
        sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", 568);
        sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", 526);
        sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", 586);
        sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p10", 526);


        for (int i = 0; i < 500 ; i+= 10) // Filling SQlite table rows and columns with values from our list 
        {


            sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", list[i]);
            sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", list[i+1]);
            sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", list[i + 2]);
            sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", list[i + 3]);
            sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", list[i + 4]);
            if (i > 490)
                break; 
            sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", list[i + 5]);
            sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", list[i + 6]);
            sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", list[i + 7]);
            sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", list[i + 8]);
            sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p10", list[i + 9]);
            sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }

        sqlite_cmd.CommandText = " DROP Table 'chang9'";
        sqlite_conn.Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not executing your command after you set the text to your drop table statement:

```
sqlite_cmd.CommandText = " DROP Table 'chang9'";
sqlite_conn.Close();
```

As such the table is never being dropped. When you attempt to run the method again the table already exists and you get the error you're seeing. You need to add a line like `sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` after setting the command text to drop your table.

```
sqlite_cmd.CommandText = " DROP Table 'chang9'";
sqlite_conn.Close();
sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Hey, pls see the comment i posted to bunyip's answer. How do I simply view this table after creating it WITHOUT getting the table already exists error?

I just want to run the program multiple times and be able to see the same table over and over.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE chang9 (Seq text, Field text, Desc text, Len text, Dec text, Typ text, Percnt text, Pop text, Alzero text, MaxLen text );";
```

when creating the table it already exists, so you can't create it again.

You assume that the table isn't there when you start this code, but it already is.

Answer (score 1):

Use below command

```
drop table if exists Table_Name
```

Comment: Yes if we use above command it will drop the already existing table. And I think this is the intention of the question.

Comment: If we assume the table exists then adding `if exists Table_Name` is equivalent to `if true` which will always pass and can be left off. If the table didn't exist the error would be different.

Comment: @Bunyip if i use the drop table if exists statement,

wont i then be unable the view the table?

Comment: I just want the program to run multiple times withoutme having to create a different table over and over. I just realized that if I use any drop table statement, my table gets destroyed before I even get to view it using an sqlite db viewer.. how would we fix that